# why isn't my environment variable visible from the command line?

Tags: macos, java, unix

I'm trying to run the james smtp server on Lion.  When I do this ...

```
sudo JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home ./james-2.3.2/bin/run.sh
```

... it works fine.

However, I'd like to make JAVA_HOME an environment variable so it is visible to other applications too.

I edited ~/.bash_profile to look like this ...

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/home
```

... and the variable appears to be visible from the command line like so ...

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/home
```

But when I run james again like this, I get a warning about JAVA_HOME ...

```
$ sudo ./james-2.3.2/bin/run.sh
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.

Please, set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Java Virtual Machine you want to use.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Why can't the command to run james see the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Any info is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Rob

Comment: Have a look here: [Setting environment variables in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/1097752)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are not running in your environment so any changes to ~/.bash_profile will have no effect on the command. It will be visible to other processes

sudo runs as another user - in this case root as you have not provided a -u username parameter. Thus you need to change the root environment to make JAVA_HOME visible to the run.sh command

Comment: You may also be able to use the `-E` option to `sudo`; the man pages say it preserves environment variables, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Thanks -- which file do I edit so the variable is visible to root user?  Also, is there a place where I can make the variable visible to the entire system?  Thanks!